# jQuery: Getting element CSS value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get padding value of a table td column. The table is styled with Bootstrap 3 CSS. But the returned value I get is empty.

Here is my working code:

```
<tr><td> <input type="text" value="abcd" /></td></tr>
```

My Javascript:

```
$("input").focus(function(e) {
            alert($(this).parent().css("padding"));
        })
```

How can I get the padding value? Thanks.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LFfgv/1/

Comment: DO not use alert for debugging especially inside focus... Use console.log. This should work fine.

Comment: even with bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZrpQk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input").focus(function(e) {
            alert($(this).parent().css("padding-top"));
        })
```

replace the top with bottom, left, right, etc.  whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('td').css('padding'));
})
```